# How can I use an array name as an array after taking it from another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

My Code:

```
 String[] rice = {"white", "brown", "none", "all"};

 String[] ingredients = {"rice", "meat", "beans", "salsa", 
 "veggies","cheese","guac", "queso", "sour cream"};

 ArrayList<String> ingredientList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++){
          ingredientList1.add(ingredients[i]);
      }
```

My Question:

I have an array of array names. When I access the names, I cannot use them. Why not? It appears to be a data type conflict -- how can I resolve it? I do not know how to convert or cast a string into a String[] array.

ingredientList1.get(i).get(0) will index the ArrayList, "rice." 
How do I use "rice" as an array name? rice[0] does not work.

Comment: _"How do I use "rice" as an array name?"_ -- You don't.  Java does not have dynamic variable names.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish with your code?  Do you need `ingredients` to include subarrays?

Comment: I wanted an array of array names that let met loop through them. Then I would reach each into array, and further loop into them. For example, I have an array of ingredients, and now I want to enter the array called rice -- such as "brown", "white", etc.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  What is the purpose of looping though these ingredients?  Depending on what you're tying to accomplish, it may make sense to just add "white rice" and "brown rice" as separate ingredients in your ingredient list.

Comment: Is there a way to convert or cast the array names in an array from String to String[]? As individual elements, they are strings, but they represent the names of arrays I've created.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to allow a random order loop through an array of categories, which loops into specific lists.

Comment: It's _technically_ possible to use reflection to get variables by their names, but it's a **terrible** idea, and you absolutely shouldn't do it.  In this case, just have a list of lists.  Every entry in `ingredients` could be a list of ingredients of a specific type.  Alternatively, you could create a new `Ingredient` object that has a name and an internal list of "types".

Comment: Perhaps a Tree would be a good match?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong idea altogether.  Arrays and lists are general purpose classes.  Looking at your strings, I assume that "white rice" and "brown rice" are probably OK combinations, but "white sour cream" and "brown sour cream" probably aren't.  What you need is a more complex class that knows how to assemble these combinations properly.  Probably each item in a "menu" needs a specific list of "options" that can be applied to it, not just one general list of options.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try another approach. I’ve only used Java for a few weeks now. I’m coming from a JavaScript background with only a slight familiarity with TypeScript, so the data type constraints are proving a huge obstacle for me at the moment— because I’m not used to working under them. I’m in a camp that will start OOP next week.

Answer (score 2):

The "rice" in your ingredients array is just a String. It has no link to the array: String[] rice.

There are many other ways to achieve what you're suggesting, but what you're specifically trying to do is reflection. In order to access the arrays by name, you would need to declare them as fields in a class, and then access the class fields using reflection. E.g. MyArrays.class.getDeclaredField....

Best to read a quick tutorial on reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

It will certainly be useful to learn about reflection, but a much better way to achieve this would be to structure your data differently, for example you could use a simple Map to store your data. The key of the map would be the ingredient, and the value would be the types of those ingredients.